# setting variables with variable names in bash (para$i=... giving "command not found")

Tags: bash, shell

I want to pass three arguments to a script,the first two numbers and third one any character,Buut when i run the script it says *command not found* ,even though the value is getting assigned.i have attached the code and image below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7gki.png)
This is my peice of code,

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
echo "insufficient argument"
for((i=$#+1;i<4;i=$i+1))
do
read -p "enter $i parameter: " x
para$i=x
done
fi
```

Comment: `para$i=x`? `x` should probably be `$x`, since you want to access the `$x` you created in the `read` line.

Comment: what's para$1? Are you sure you dont intend to use array? Also why would you process when you have insufficient argument?

Comment: If you want to perform an indirect assignment, see [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: That said, since your shebang says bash, you have arrays; you should use them (and you should be tagging your question "bash", not just "shell"). Your C-style `for` loops are also extended syntax, making a bash tag even more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid assignment:

```
para$i=x
```

Since your shell is bash, you can do the following instead:

```
# bash 3.1 or higher
printf -v "para$i" %s "$x"
```

...or...

```
# bash 4.3 or higher; works with arrays and other tricky cases too.
declare -n para="para$i"
para=$x
unset -n para
```

...or...

```
# any POSIX shell
# be very careful about the quoting; only safe if $x is quoted and $i is a controlled value
eval "para$i=\$x"
```

---

See [the BashFAQ #6 section on indirect assignment](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

See an example of processing a parameter called process_date
The script this will accept the parameter as so:

```
some_sh_script.sh -process_date=01/01/2016
```

Script:

```
process_date=""

while test "$1" != "" ; do

    # Test argument syntax e.g. -someName=someValue or help operators
    if [[ $1 != -*=*  &&  $1 != -h  &&  $1 != -help ]]
        then
            echo "Error in $0 - $1 - Argument syntax invalid."
            usage
        exit 1
    fi
    # END Test argument syntax

    # Split argument name & value by `=` delimiter
    paramName=`echo $1 | cut -d '=' -f1`
    paramVal=`echo $1 | cut -d '=' -f2`

    case $paramName in          

        -process_date)  
                process_date=$paramVal
            ;;


        #User help parameter
        -help|-h)
                usage
                exit 0
        ;;
        -*)
                echo "No such option $1"
                usage
                exit 1
        ;;
    esac    

    #parse next argument
    shift
done
```